# Select specific lines in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array with certain lines I want to select, those being `A` and `B`:

```
[0] A1
[1] line I don't want to select
[2] B1
[3] line I don't want to select
[4] A2
[5] line I don't want to select
[6] B2
[7] line I don't want to select
[8] line I don't want to select
[9] line I don't want to select
[10] A3
[11] line I don't want to select
[12] B3
```

There is always one line apart lines containing `A` and lines containing `B`, so in this example those lines would be `[1]`, `[5]`, `[11]`

I want to select all lines that would contain `A`, then pair them with their respective lines containing `B` and create a new array that would look like this:

```
[1] A1,B1
[2] A2,B2
[3] A3,B3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try regex :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Select_specific_lines_in_an_array
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line = "";
            int count = 0;

            List<List<string>> testlist = new List<List<string>>();
            List<string> templist = new List<string>();

            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(FILENAME);

            string pattern = @"^(?'letter'[A-Z]+)(?'number'\d+)$";

            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();

                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern);

                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Letter : '{0}', Number : '{1}'", match.Groups["letter"], match.Groups["number"]);
                        templist.Add(line);
                        if (templist.Count == 2)
                        {
                            testlist.Add(templist);
                            templist = new List<string>();
                        }
                    }
                }
                count = count + 1;
            }
            file.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Select_specific_lines_in_an_array
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line = "";
            int count = 0;

            List<List<string>> testlist = new List<List<string>>();
            List<string> templist = new List<string>(); 

            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("inputfile.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line != "line I don't want to select")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    templist.Add(line);
                    if (templist.Count == 2)
                    {
                        testlist.Add(templist);
                        templist = new List<string>();
                    }
                }
                count = count + 1;
            }
            file.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of the while loop the testlist will look like this:
[image]

Note this is not perfect code the problem with it is:
-it relies upon it going A1 B1 if it goes A1 A2 then the program will still run
 and work however it wont be storing the A1 and B1 together it will be storing
 A1 and A2 together

However i think this should be enough to give u a starting point to work off.

Also just as a last note i used a list containing list instead of multidimensional array as we dont know at the start how many pieces of data there is that we want.

Edit - sample input text

```
A1
line I don't want to select
B1
line I don't want to select
A2
line I don't want to select
B2
line I don't want to select
line I don't want to select
line I don't want to select
line I don't want to select
A3
line I don't want to select
B3
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the input text.  Usually when input text from a file you are reading more than one record.  So you first have to identify where each record starts in the text file and then count from the start or the record the number of lines.  When the next record is started you have to start the count again.  I've been doing this for over 40 years.  And can help, but need to see original text.

Comment: I just made a text file and copy and pasted his text that he put at the start of his question and took out the line numbers. Also the count i put in at the start encase i needed it but forgot to take it out when i didn't end up using it.